# how to configure eb cli with eb env that is already running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have taken over a project that has been deployed to elastic beanstalk.  I would like to configure my eb cli to deploy to the existing environment without modifying that environment.  From my research I get the impression that `eb init` is the proper command, however when I started going through the interactive session it seemed like it was going to use my entries as the configuration settings (e.g. platform version).  I want to make sure that I maintain the settings that are already in use (I was unable to determine what platform version my running environment is using) and I want to make sure that the running ec2 instance will not be replaced or terminated for any reason.  Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

During `eb init` make sure select an existing application and environment. As long as you do this it will pull down the settings from the environment.

However, that being said, the settings that `eb init` creates are default setting used for future environments. It will not overwrite any settings on any running environments.

As far as instances, Elastic Beanstalk can terminate or create instances at anytime based on health and autoscaling. However, if we assume your instances are healthy and no autoscaling events occur, then `eb deploy` will never cause instances to be replaced.

I am however a little curious as to why you are so worried about your instances being replaced.

As far as determining your current platform, you can get that information from `eb status`.

Comment: As long as we put they `.ppk` key in the `.ssh` folder first before `eb init`

Comment: for me `eb init` or `eb init -i ` is not showing Mumbai region , what could be the reason?

Comment: @PiyushSWanare The CLI probably hasn't added support for the new region yet.

Comment: Wow. Make sure to choose the right region. I am new to EB and didn't think it mattered! Cost me a whole day of frustration.

Answer (score 18):

Better way is to configure you aws cli using aws configure or manually create -

`~/.aws/config` with

```
[profilename]
region = ap-south-1
```

`~/.aws/credentials` with

```
[profilename]
aws_secret_access_key = abc
aws_access_key_id = pqr
```

and then use -

```
eb init --profile profilename
```

Comment: On my aws eb cli I have to put `[profile <my_profile_name>]`. That is, there must be the word "profile" followed by a space, followed by the profile name, all in square brackets.

Comment: Config file must contain the prefix "profile" i.e. [profile profilename]. Credentials does not have this requirement. "The credentials file uses a different naming format than the CLI config file for named profiles. Include the prefix word "profile" only when configuring a named profile in the config file. Do not use the word profile when creating an entry in the credentials file."  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: How can i find my aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key from the AWS eb console ??

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Everything seems to connect correctly but I don't see any of my applications or environments with eb list