# Elastic Beanstalk CLI ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI You must first run "eb init"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssh, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to connect to my elastic beanstalk application that I created in the web browser console over CLI but every time I try to do anything it says I have not set up the directory with EB CLI and I must first run 'eb init'. However, I do not want to create a new application I simply want to access the old one over terminal/cmd so I can deploy my nodejs to it. How can I access it over CLI without creating a new application with 'eb init'?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to configure eb cli with eb env that is already running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821632/how-to-configure-eb-cli-with-eb-env-that-is-already-running)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 'eb init', you can choose an existing application/environment. Choose your existing app/env and it will download the settings from that and stores it in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file. You can double check that file and do your future 'eb deploy's.